# HTML, href is spreading its self over 6 lines when it only needs one

Tags: html, formatting, line, href

I am using VS Code with a prettier extension added.
I try to write a line that contains a "href" like this:

```
<p><a href="https://cosprings.craigslist.org?search_distance=30&postal=81212">Craigslist</a></p>
```

But every time I save the project it takes up six lines:

```
<p>
  <a
    href="https://cosprings.craigslist.org?search_distance=30&postal=81212"
    >Craigslist</a
  >
</p>
```

I have the same problem with two of the other "href" lines in my code. But I also have "href" lines that format correctly.

I am only trying to make a simple link page with a bunch of "href"s on it.

What can I do to get the line to format correctly?

Comment: Looks like default JSX formatting. Try updating prettier config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the settings for the Prettier extension and change the "Print Width" setting.

Comment: @Reinald Brown That worked! I changed the "Print Width" to 100 and it helped a little. Then I changed it to 1,000 and it fixed my problem! Thanks!